Retrieve user with wordpress rest API
I want to retrieve users from a wordpress database with rest API and then put them in my postgresSQL database.
I created endpoints in my back in nestjs but when I go to postman, I get this error:
{
"statusCode": 400,
"message": "Invalid user ID"
}.
I don't understand how to solve it.
Here are the codes that come into play:
  async userFromWordpress(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const response = await this.httpService
        .get(
          'example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users',
        )
        .toPromise();
      const users = response.data;
      for (const userData of users) {
        const user = new User();
        user.userLogin = userData.user_login;
        user.userPass = userData.user_pass;
        user.userNicename = userData.user_nicename;
        user.userEmail = userData.user_email;
        user.userUrl = userData.user_url;
        user.userRegistered = new Date(userData.user_registered);

        if (!isNaN(userData.user_status)) {
          user.userStatus = Number(userData.user_status);
        } else {
          console.error(
            "La valeur de 'userData.user_status' n'est pas un nombre valide :",
            userData.user_status,
          );
          user.userStatus = 0; 
        }

        user.displayName = userData.display_name;

        await this.userRepository.save(user);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(
        "Erreur lors de la récupération des utilisateurs depuis l'API WordPress :",
        error.message,
      );
    }
  }

 @Get('import-wordpress-users')
  async importWordpressUsers() {
    try {
      await this.userService.userFromWordpress();
      return {
        message: 'Les utilisateurs de WordPress ont été importés avec succès.',
      };
    } catch (error) {
      return {
        error: "Erreur lors de l'importation des utilisateurs de WordPress.",
      };
    }
  }

I tried many things my modifiyng the userFromWordpress() methods but I don't understand how to solve the error
